# Tables are not displayed

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-insert

I worked with database tables... Paradoxically, I clicked somewhere else and now there are no these tables. More precisely, sql developer does not show them, unless you call select * from name_table and then only through f5. Otherwise, he does not show information. What should I do to have SQL developer output table data again?

If anyone has faced such a problem, please tell me!

Such a script should have been originally:

```
CREATE TABLE "SPISOK_DOLGNOSTY"
( "KOD_DOLGN" NUMBER(*,0),
"NAME_DOLGN" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
REM INSERTING into SPISOK_DOLGNOSTY
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into SPISOK_DOLGNOSTY (KOD_DOLGN,NAME_DOLGN) values (1,'Директор предприятия');
Insert into SPISOK_DOLGNOSTY (KOD_DOLGN,NAME_DOLGN) values (2,'Ведущий инженер');
Insert into SPISOK_DOLGNOSTY (KOD_DOLGN,NAME_DOLGN) values (5,'Доцент');
Insert into SPISOK_DOLGNOSTY (KOD_DOLGN,NAME_DOLGN) values (9,'Канцелярист');
Insert into SPISOK_DOLGNOSTY (KOD_DOLGN,NAME_DOLGN) values (12,'Начальник отдела кадров');
Insert into SPISOK_DOLGNOSTY (KOD_DOLGN,NAME_DOLGN) values (20,'Старший преподаватель');
Insert into SPISOK_DOLGNOSTY (KOD_DOLGN,NAME_DOLGN) values (21,'Техник первой категории');
Insert into SPISOK_DOLGNOSTY (KOD_DOLGN,NAME_DOLGN) values (118,'Сантехник');
Insert into SPISOK_DOLGNOSTY (KOD_DOLGN,NAME_DOLGN) values (120,'Кадровик');
--------------------------------------------------------
-- DDL for Index SYS_C007193
--------------------------------------------------------

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "SYS_C007193" ON "SPISOK_DOLGNOSTY" ("KOD_DOLGN")
PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS
STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
--------------------------------------------------------
-- DDL for Index SYS_C007112
--------------------------------------------------------

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "SYS_C007112" ON "SPISOK_DOLGNOSTY" ("NAME_DOLGN")
PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS
STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
--------------------------------------------------------
-- Constraints for Table SPISOK_DOLGNOSTY
--------------------------------------------------------

ALTER TABLE "SPISOK_DOLGNOSTY" ADD UNIQUE ("NAME_DOLGN")
USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS
STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "USERS" ENABLE;
ALTER TABLE "SPISOK_DOLGNOSTY" ADD PRIMARY KEY ("KOD_DOLGN")
USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS
STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "USERS" ENABLE;
ALTER TABLE "SPISOK_DOLGNOSTY" MODIFY ("NAME_DOLGN" NOT NULL ENABLE);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGsvi.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trd1C.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9uxG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGIcm.png)

Comment: Did you drop and recreate the tables? If so have you closed the table-specific tabs and then clicked on the names again in the explorer panel? Or failing that, quit and relaunched SQL Developer?

Comment: what version of sql developer?

Answer (score 0):

Your DDL, used on a Oracle 12cR2 database, running in a more recent version of SQL Developer (20.0), works just fine.

[image]

Try:

- restarting the application
- check the log panel for errors
- UPGRADE your software, it's free and just a simple UnZip and go